# Initial username/password for Kubuntu 20.x

Tags: kubuntu, password

I just started up the VirtualBox VM of Kubuntu 20.x, and it is asking me for a username/password. I've tried root/root, ubuntu/ubuntu, and kubuntu/kubuntu. Nothing works.

Does anyone know what this is?

Comment: How did you install Kubuntu in the Virtual?

Comment: If someone installed it for you, ask them what they set.  Ubuntu does not have defaults like some routers/other stuff do.  It is made during installation.